# Vim Editor :last-child and :first-child nested css error

Tags: css, vim, sass

I've started Vim (v8) and have proper syntax highlighters in place for css3. I am using postcss plugin called precss to provide for "SASS" like syntax in my code.

However, when I used a nested selector with "&:last-child" or &:first-child, the syntax throws an error. It doesn't break the code or anything, but that "red" error is so distracting for me. Check the screen shot below.

Anyone can figure out how to make this error go?? I use a plugin called vim-css3-syntax and it includes scss syntax highlighting.

Edit: Got it fixed by downloading https://github.com/cakebaker/scss-syntax.vim and then adding `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.css set filetype=scss.css`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The filetype of that buffer is almost certainly `css`, where there's no `&`. Change it to either `sass` or `scss`.

Comment: Ok, but I am not using sass or scss. What do I do now? I am using postcss and a plugin called precss.

Comment: No. What you are writing is either SASS or SCSS (nesting + `&`), therefore you can't expect it to be valid CSS, therefore you get CSS errors. Use the right filetype.

Comment: I am not using SASS exactly. I use PostCSS - and it has a plugin that allows for syntax like SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are using SCSS syntax (nested blocks, `&`, etc.) in CSS makes your CSS invalid.

If you want to avoid syntax errors you have two paths:

- stop using SCSS syntax in your CSS files,
- make sure your file is recognized as what it is: SCSS.

I would consider the first path to be the most sensible. After all who writes JavaScript in a `*.rb` file or SCSS in a `*.css` file? But if you choose the second you can simply do:

```
setf scss
```

--- edit ---

Suppose we have this code:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}
```

It's both valid CSS *and* valid SCSS because SCSS is a *superset* of CSS. Any valid CSS is automatically valid SCSS. Vim will happily display it without any error, no matter what file extension (`*.css`, `*.scss`) and filetype (`css`, `scss`).

Now, suppose we have this code:

```
body {
    h1 {
        background-color: $brand-1;
    }
}
```

It's valid SCSS but not valid CSS. If you write that code in a `*.css` file with the `css` filetype, you get errors because it's not CSS. If you write that code in a `*.scss` file with the `scss` filetype you don't get errors because it's valid SCSS.

Comment: The entire point here is I am not using SASS to actually include a .scss extension. I am using POSTCSS and it is definitely allowed to write SCSS syntax in CSS files. Also, the comparison that you give makes absolutely no sense. SCSS is not a different language. It's just a preprocessor. Like what coffeescript is to javascript. You are allowed to write coffeescript in js files aren't you?

Comment: What you can put in a CSS file is defined by a standard and the script used by Vim to define the syntax of CSS files follows that standard. Since CSS doesn't allow nesting you can't reasonably expect the default syntax script to allow nesting. **The facts that you use PostCSS and that you don't care about standards is totally unknown to both Vim and the default syntax script for CSS.** This is why you get errors: what you write in that `*.css` file is not valid CSS. If you don't want errors, use a filetype that fits what you are *actually* writing: `scss`.